Loud sound in Europe

Grid in Penpa+
Across

1. Extend support to Peter regularly - right thing done (8)
5. Discourage not taking into account what conclusion does? (4)
8. Anvil fashioned from corporation at America (5)
9. Do a job on the side of satellite - not great in terms of load (9)
11. Inspect a loud sound, one through European region (11)
12. God in the Bible seen late in the night (1 2)
13. Passionate about avoiding vehicular damage? (6)
14. Saint Helena's chief patrol back for checkers (8)
16. Certain hat being woven together (2 3 3)
19. A key figure leading to Jesus' death, an investigator, near the end of the day (6)
22. Pass clothes retailer opening somewhere in France (3)
23. Party that's interested vampire slayer? (11)
24. On agreed upon time, not quite ready - that's time you'll never get back (9)
25. Note what's seen on every piece of this American chocolate candy? (5)
26. Standing above with good grade to pass (4)
27. Move on, entering large club (8)

Down

1. Meticulously draw a majestic drawing in front of spectators (13)
2. Golden vegetable with nutritious leaves found in garden (7)
3. Before this age, walls torn down from leader's home (9)
4. On the way to search for rocks, while almost done putting on gear (6)
5. Land at river's end coped with a depressed heart (5)
6. British rock single with hard support (7)
7. You finished kicking ball under the sun (6)
10. Affected mom in a Western newspaper's original style (5 3 5)
15. Ignorant, ignorant of knight in special attire (9)
17. Compose category and group (7)
18. Honors received by retiring artists draw attention (6)
20. An Italian writer played quite slowly (7)
21. Doctor with double life flubbed key lines while facing judge (6)
23. Perhaps Jesus, as encapsulated by Is. fifty-three, ultimately at the middle of chapter! (5)

This is a cryptic crossword. The check mark will go to the first person who submits an answer with 1) an image of the completed crossword and 2) explanations for all clue answers. For users who cannot use Imgur, reproduce the completed crossword through table/code formatting. If you solve using Penpa+, all letters entered must be capitalized and the color used must be either green, blue, or red (otherwise it will not be able to check the answer).
Cryptic clue guide by Deusovi
Cryptic crossword on Wikipedia
Grid generated by Qxw

(Merry Christmas!)

Finished grid

 
<

Clue explanations

 


Yes, well done! I will give you the check mark, but I suggest being more explicit about the wordplay in rot13(gjryir npebff. Fcrpvsvpnyyl V fhttrfg nqqvat fbzrguvat yvxr "(bar nz)" (V fcryyrq vg bhg urer fb gung vg jba'g or rnfvyl qrpvcurerq sebz gur bhgfvqr, ohg chggvat whfg gur ahzore'f flzoby vgfrys jbexf gbb bsp) nsgre gur nafjre.)

Addendum: I came back to this and thought that rot13(lbh zvtug nyfb jnag gb fcrpvsl jung pnaql jr'er ersreevat gb va gjragl-svir npebff).

@oAlt that should do it!
